# Sort QGraphicsItems QList based on center point min to max

Tags: c++, qt

How can I sort a list of QGraphicsItems based on their boundingRect center point? I would like the list to be sorted from min Y value to max Y value.

thanks

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> validItems;

foreach (QGraphicsItem* item, items) {
    if (!item) continue;
    if (item->type() == NexusBlockItem::Type) {
        int nodeCenterY = item->pos().y() + (item->boundingRect().height()/2.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt provides a nice function for this purpose: `qSort()`

```
bool itemLess(const QGraphicsItem* item1, const QGraphicsItem* item2)
{
    return item1->sceneBoundingRect().center().y() < item2->sceneBoundingRect().center.y();
}

qSort(validItems.begin(), validItems.end(), itemLess);
```

**Note 1**: You can use `std::sort()` instead of `qSort()`.

**Note 2**: You can use a *functor* or *lambda* to compare the items instead of `itemLess()` function.

**Note 3**: Both `qSort()` and `std::sort()` use the *quicksort* algorithm.

**EDIT**

As **vicrucann** mentioned, the Qt documentation recommends to use a `std::sort()` instead of `qSort()`.

Comment: [it is recommended](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html#qSort) to use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`.

Comment: how is this written just using sort then?

Comment: yes, same way: `std::sort(validItems.begin(), validItems.end(), itemLess)`; the comparison function `itemLess()` remains the same.

Comment: why do i get this error when using the example?

error: 'item2->QGraphicsItem::sceneBoundingRect().QRectF::center' does not have class type
     return item1->sceneBoundingRect().center().y() < item2->sceneBoundingRect().center.y();
                                                      ^

Comment: you are calling a *center()* method without parentheses